# Prevent remote desktop connection closing / timing out

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 machine that I connect to via RDP

If I leave a load of applications open on the machine, then step away from the machine for say, an hour, when I reconnect, it starts a fresh session - like the machine has restarted
(Obviously losing any work I was stupid enough not to save)

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: You can from the server side if you have access? Chances are it's timing out and killing the session https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=keep+rdp+session+open&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MHYuVLuvCenY8gfv94G4CQ

Comment: I'm RDP'ing from one desktop to another, on same LAN